# How to accept any method call in JMockit?

Tags: stub, jmockit

I have something like the following code:

```
public void f() {
    logger.info("some string");
}
```

How would I specify in JMockit that any call to logger is allowed?  For example, if someone changed the logger call to:

```
    logger.finest("some string");
```

the test should still pass.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an stubbed-out mock class, as per http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/StateBasedTesting.html:

```
@MockClass(realClass = Logger.class, stubs = "", inverse = true)
static class MockLoggerStub { }
```

Then just call this before running your test:

```
Mockit.setUpMocks(MockLoggerStub.class);
```

This will completely stub out the Logger class for your test.

Comment: This looks like it's on the right track.  Is there a way I can get a stub object out of this?  My constructor takes in the logger instance as a parameter (for dependency injection).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think you can use this style of mocking to get a stub object for later use.  For that I think you would have to go down the "Behavior Based Testing" route.  See http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#partial